# Issue on scaling a Canvas in Android

Tags: android, canvas, scale

I have a code to scale drawing canvas.
So i tried this code. i scale it but it moves down,

here is my code:

```
canvas.save();
scaleA = 1.1;
scaleB = 1.1;
canvas.scale(scaleA, scaleB);
canvas.restore();
```

the issue is even when i scale the `Y` coordinates move down, so i try to translate or reduce y coordinates but i still issue. any one knows how to properly scale a drawing canvas?

i tried like this:

```
canvas.save();
scaleA = 1.1;
scaleB = 1.1;
canvas.translate(scaleA, -scaleB);
canvas.scale(scaleA, scaleB);
canvas.restore();
```

Comment: Can you add images for current behavior and expected outcome ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the center of your image, if your image center is equal to the canvas(view) center

```
canvas.scale(sx, sy, canvas.getWidth() / 2, canvas.getHeight() / 2);
```

Or else, change the last two params to whatever center you want it to be, you don't need to translate

Comment: sorry this help me solve the issue,, i just re adjust it